# Overlap content of <p> box

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML snippet:

```
<p id="meinFader">
    <img src="http://tierarztpraxis-miehlen.com/images/slide2.jpg" alt="Picture_1" width="100%">
    <img src="http://tierarztpraxis-miehlen.com/images/slide1.jpg" alt="Picture_2" width="100%" class="next">
    <img src="http://tierarztpraxis-miehlen.com/images/slide3.jpg" alt="Picture_3" width="100%" class="next">
</p>
```

And now I want to make the images overlap each other. They have the same size, so there is no problem. I once had this task done by adding an entry into the .css file, but I can't remember how it worked.

Any help?

Comment: Remove `width="100%"`, it's a presentational attribute now deprecated in HTML5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
#meinFader {
    position: relative;
}

#meinFader > img {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Modified according to Bojan's comment. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qj4dzkz4/3/)

Comment: this made the pictures disappear completely in the first try :-/

Comment: What do you mean by disappear? One picture should be visible. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qj4dzkz4/2/)

Comment: Add position relative to the parent #meinFader so the images are absolutely positioned to the parent